# Pass objects to silverlight through server side asp.net code

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Is it possible to pass objects (serializable classes or other ways) to a Silverlight control through asp.net server side code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's going to involve serialization.  Remember -- your Silverlight client is disconnected from the server, just like the browser is disconnected from the server.

There is a great article [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/JSON-serialization-and-deserialization-in-Silverlight.aspx) on JSON serialization to and from Silverlight.  Here is the summary from the article:

Let’s start with a short introduction of what JSON is. It stands for **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation and is used as an alternative of the XML. Here is a simple example for a JSON file:

`{"FirstName":"Martin","LastName":"Mihaylov"}` for a single object

And

`[{"FirstName":"Martin","LastName":"Mihaylov"},{"FirstName":"Emil","LastName":"Stoychev"}]` for multiple objects.

It looks like an array. Depending on the object that is serialized it could look really complicated.

### Serializing

In order to be serializable with DataContractJsonSerializer we have to set a [DataContract] attribute. The properites that will be used by the serialization must have [DataMember] attributes. Note: To use these attributes add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization;

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

Now we are ready to begin with the serialization. Let's create a method that takes our object as an argument and returns a string in JSON format:

```
public static string SerializeToJsonString(object objectToSerialize)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
        serializer.WriteObject(ms, objectToSerialize);
        ms.Position = 0;


        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }

}
```

### Deserializing

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string jsonString)
{

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
    {

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));


        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

    }

}
```

Here is what this looks like from client code:

```
List<Person> persons = Deserialize<List<Person>>( jsonString );
```

Comment: How do I pass that to the silverlight control?  Do I just register a script block on the page, then look for a javascript variable somehow in the silverlight control?